# How to setup VSCode so that nodejs typescript classes and client side typescript classes can be used together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is there a way to setup VSCode so that my nodejs typescript classes and my client side typescript classes can be used together?

In other words if I have created ValueObject classes for use in my nodejs ts files, I want to use those types in my client side TS / Javascript code.

This is not going to be an easy question.

Before you say no, I have it partially working but it only works under certain conditions. If those conditions aren't met, nodejs throws errors. If the class I reference from my client side Javascript / Typescript is fairly basic and the same ts file doesn't have any imports it seems to work. If I do imports it seems nodejs compiling fails with errors (sometimes I get cannot import into a module and other errors).

I have a node express server running Typescript in the root directory and in the public directory I have HTML pages and client side Typescript and transpiled Javascript files.

```
Project: 
/server.ts
/routes.ts
/Classes.ts
/ValueClass.ts
/tsconfig.json
/routes/route1.ts
/routes/route2.ts
/public/index.html
/public/index.ts
/public/ttsconfig.json
```

I can start the server and nodejs will build the nodejs project:
[image]

```
// the default directory path for web pages 
app.use(express.static('public'));

// start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
  console.clear();
  console.log(`App running at http://localhost:${PORT} at ${time}`);
})
```

Note: Before attempting this procedure I didn't see any js files in the root directory after starting nodejs. They are all .ts files.

Then, I build the client side Typescript / Javascript code using Command+shift+B:

```
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "public/ttsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "tsc: build - public/ttsconfig.json"
        }
```

That compiles or transpiles some or all of the .ts in `/public` directory. After this I have multiple .js files sitting next to the .ts files.

So far everything is working.

Now, if one of my client side TS files, let's say `/public/index.ts`, imports a class from the root directory, like a value object class `/ValueObject.ts`, then in the root directory a .js file is created, `/ValueObject.js`. This class is very basic.

```
export type ValueObject = {
   name: string;
   index: number;
   type: string;
}
```

If the .ts file in the root directory is fairly basic it works. My client side TS/JS now can use a type from nodejs side and get Typescript assistance simply by importing it.

Example code:
/public/index.ts:

```
import { ValueObject } from "../ValueObject.js"; // go up a directory and use a node ts class

var myObject: ValueObject; // typed variable
```

The above works. But when I import a different .ts file or a more complex ts file nodejs compiling breaks with different errors. Sometimes it doesn't like an import statement, sometimes it gets stuck on the export keyword:

```
example ts: 
export {};

export type UnknownType = 'Unknown';

Nodejs Compiling Error: 
"/OtherClass.js:"
export var UNKNOWN = "Unknown";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
  at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
  at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
```

It seems that when the client side typescript compiler that runs in the sub directory `/public` starts creating client side .js in the root directory the server side typescript node compiler picks up the .js files instead of referencing the .ts files and it doesn't seem to like that code.

If I had to guess, it might be that my typescript tsconfig.json in the root directory is generating different incompatible output than the typescript tsconfig.json in the public directory. If the root tsconfig could skip the .js files it might work.

Here are my tsconfig files.

The nodejs tsconfig pretty much has to stay the same. The JS config can be changed.

/tsconfig.json (nodejs settings):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ES6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "stripInternal": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

/public/tsconfig.json (client side settings):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "stripInternal": true,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
    "resolveJsonModule" : true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["es2022", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "include": [
      "*.ts",
      "/public/**/*.ts",
      "./public/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node",
    "./node_modules",
    "/node_modules",
    "../../node_modules",
    "../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Note:
I've been changing the export options for nodejs because I think that is where the issue is. This is one error:

```
/server.ts:1
import express from "express";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've changing the target and module and module resolution in nodejs tsconfig.

If I change the module support in the client tsconfig then nodejs compiles but then the client side page gives this error:

```
page.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

// that line:  
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

I found one really hacky workaround:

- Create the client side code first
- When nodejs compiler runs somehow delete, hide or move the js files. I don't know how to do this

I've created a related post here:
[Duplicate a class to a subdirectory on save in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78003271/duplicate-a-class-to-a-subdirectory-on-save-in-vscode)

```
Related error from nodejs compiler: 

[/Users/MyConstants.js:18
export var MY_CONSTANT = "value";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Comment: Your module configurations conflict. Have you tried setting them to the same thing? Your tsconfigs should be almost identical (except for `lib`).

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev yes. good find. i spent some time setting them to the same thing and one would work and the other wouldn't. I tried node, node16, nodenext, es2020, etc. I went through a lot of them but it doesn't mean there isn't a compatible setting. I had one that worked for nodejs but the client side js didn't work, `"exports" not defined` error (see post). I believe i could fix that error if I would add `exports = {}` at the top of the every page that loads the modules. but that feels fragile and might break things in the future or prevent future features.

Comment: vscode guys refuse to make a UI for tsconfig.json. doing that would prove that it does or doesn't work. i have spent enough time on this that as a model the json config doesn't work or theirs doesnt. a ui would have fixed this issue instantly. "Do you want a tsconfig that supports server and client?"